# Show that the limit $\lim_{z \to 0}{\frac{\sin(i\bar{z})}{z}}$ doesn't exist in $\mathbb{C}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that the limit $\lim_{z \to 0}{\frac{\sin(i\bar{z})}{z}}$ doesn't exist in $\mathbb{C}$.

Any hint helps. I tried by writing $z$ as $ x+iy$ and $\bar{z}$ as $ x-iy$ and looking at the formula for $\sin(z)$ but got nowhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: 
Evaluate the limit for $z=iy$ and $z=x$. With $x$ and $y$ both real numbers